# Nested Loop Formatting

Tags: haskell

I am trying to produce an output where the input list is split each time f x is true. I use two variables to keep track of the substring and the final list, and this function will be called by another that provides empty lists for two tracking variables. Example desired output:

```
separate odd [1,2,3,4] = [[2],[4]]
```

Below is what I have so far - although I keep running into type errors because lists all have to be of the same type - can anyone advise what changes need to be made to produce the desired output?

```
separate f (x:xs) sublist finalstr
  | f x = (finalstr ++ sublist) : separate f xs sublist finalstr
  | otherwise = (sublist ++ x) : separate f xs sublist finalstr
separate f [] sublist finalstr = []
```

Comment: In the first case, you call `separate` and add an element to the resulting list and put that in a list again. So if `separate` was something like `[[2]]` the result would be something like `[[[3],[2]]]` or so and that is not, what you wanted.
Also `sublist` never grows, separate is always called with the same `sublist` from the first call.

Comment: @typetetris I'm sort of following you. I updated the code a bit, however not quite sure where to go from there/if that made any difference

Comment: I suggest, you try to evaluate `separate odd [1,2,3,4] [] []` with pencil and paper and see where it leads you.

Answer (score 1):

You could divide your problem into the following sub-problems:

1. Group each element in the list by what `f` returns:

   ```
   groupOn :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [[a]]
   groupOn f = ...
   ```

   For example,

   ```
   > groupOn odd [1,3,3,4,5,6,8]
   [[1,3,3],[4],[5],[6,8]]
   ```
2. Filter out sub-lists in which the first element satisfies `f`:

   ```
   separate :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
   separate f xs = filter (\ys -> ...) (groupOn f xs)
   ```

   where `ys` would be `[1,3,3]`, `[4]`, `[5]` and `[6,8]` in the above example.

Comment: thank you, this is very helpful. How are you getting sublists from groupOn? I have:
f x = x : groupOn f xs
  | otherwise = groupOn f xs
and this only returns a single list