# Haskell Nested Loops

Tags: haskell

I am trying to split a list whenever `f` returns true, for example:

```
separate even [1,2,3,4] = [[2],[4]]
```

Current code:

```
separate f (x:xs) currentstr finalstr
  | f x = (finalstr ++ currentstr) : separate  f xs [] finalstr
  | otherwise = (currentstr ++ x) : separate  f xs (currentstr + x) finalstr
separate  f [] currentstr finalstr = []
```

Can anyone provide some insight on how to fix this? Values for `currentstr` and `finalstr` will be provided as `[]` in another function always, so this is not a concern.

Comment: Could you define a little bit better the behaviour you want? It seems you are looking for filter or similar

Comment: @Ismor I just want to be able to filter with a given f and split each list value at f being true - so separate odd [1,2,2,3,3] = [[2,2]]. Does that hep?

Comment: @SimonShine my apologies. Are you able to identify what I need to modify to fix this so I can accept an answer on here?

Comment: @KiraLe: You say that something needs to be fixed, but it's a little unclear what that is. It seems to me that this is a homework question and that you're stuck. Normally you either go back and try and solve a simpler exercise first, or try and split this problem into simpler sub-problems that can be solved more easily one at a time.

Comment: @KiraLe It is *not* clear at all what you mean. Up to your comment `separate odd [1,2,2,3,3] = [[2,2]]` meaning that odd numbers should be considered tokens and what remains are the parts of the list that are not tokens. Whereas in the question `separate even [1,2,3,4] = [[2],[4]]` behaves exactly the opposite. ???

Comment: @SimonShine that duplicate was deleted by the asker. I voted to undelete, and flagged asking for undeletion as well. (both Qs have nothing to do with nested loops, incidentally).

Comment: I would advise you to consider folding.

Comment: @SimonShine maybe [it'll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59044765/nested-loop-formatting) get undeleted yet.

Comment: @SimonShine that post's author has again deleted it (complete with their "thank you" to you in the comments). I invite you to flag it so it gets more attention and they are explained by a mod that this is unacceptable behavior.

Comment: @WillNess: I suspect this is because the author uses their full name to ask for help on a homework assignment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested Loop Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59044765/nested-loop-formatting)

Comment: @WillNess It's re-undeleted now, and I also upvoted the answer, so he can't unilaterally delete it again.

Answer (score 1):

You could divide your problem into the following sub-problems:

1. Split a list in two where the first sequence is equivalent when applying `f` to each element:

   ```
   splitOn :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
   splitOn f [] = ...
   splitOn f (x:xs) = ...
   ```

   For example,

   ```
   > splitOn odd [1,3,3,4,5]
   ([1,3,3], [4,5])
   ```
2. Group each element in the list by what `f` returns:

   ```
   groupOn :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [[a]]
   groupOn f [] = ...
   groupOn f xs = ...
   ```

   For example,

   ```
   > groupOn odd [1,3,3,4,5,6,8]
   [[1,3,3],[4],[5],[6,8]]
   ```

   You can do this by applying `splitOn` recursively. Think *case-of*.
3. Filter out sub-lists in which the first element satisfies `f`:

   ```
   separate :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
   separate f xs = filter (\ys -> ...) (groupOn f xs)
   ```

   where `ys` would be `[1,3,3]`, `[4]`, `[5]` and `[6,8]` in the above example.